# How to display HTML from resources by using NovodaTils

Tags: android, android-webview

How can I use [NovodaTils](https://github.com/novoda/notils) in order to display a html from resources to my activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have your html code stored in a file inside your `raw` resource folder of the project. Then use `RawWebView` in your android layouts, call `RawWebView.loadRawResource(R.raw.my_html_file)` in order to display the html.